# Not able to select a tag in Alfresco Community 5.0.d

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-ldap

I am using Alfresco Community 5.0.d and when I go to edit properties then click on select tag, I get below error in view.

```
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 00170047
```

Below is error in console.

```
"status": {
"code": 500,
"name": "Internal Error",
"description": "An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request."
},
"message": "org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 00170049 ",
"exception": "",
"callstack": [],
"server": "Community v5.0.0 (d r99759-b2) schema 8,022",
"time": "Jan 17, 2017 10:14:59 PM"
}
```

Below is screenshot of the view.

[image: tag issue]

Link for alfresco log file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzmMymYRd2jwemFZSU5lV2MzMlk

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant alfresco.log file info?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzmMymYRd2jwemFZSU5lV2MzMlk here you can find the alfresco.log file

Comment: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431) . How is ur SOLR is configured and does your SOLR is running correctly ?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196265/sslpeerunverifiedexception-during-attempted-upload

Comment: Thank you for useful comment. If you could post your comment then I could accept it as answer.

Comment: Please paste the relevant log section (and a bit around) to your question, otherwise it it not a fully-contained question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your log file information, there is an issue with your SOLR.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessi‌​onImpl.java:431) . How is ur SOLR is configured and does your SOLR is running correctly ?
```

Refer this post, [SSLPeerUnverifiedException During attempted upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196265/sslpeerunverifiedexception-during-attempted-upload)