# Failed to execute script in Alfresco community 5.0.d

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-ldap, alfresco-maven

I am using Alfresco Community 5.0.d and facing below error.

```
    LuceneQueryParserException with findSites()
 org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 00180032 
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:540)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:51)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.DbOrIndexSwitchingQueryLanguage.executeQuery(DbOrIndexSwitchingQueryLanguage.java:214)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:348)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.SearcherComponent.query(SearcherComponent.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.query(SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.site.SiteServiceImpl.findSites(SiteServiceImpl.java:928)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.CheckTransactionAdvice.invoke(CheckTransactionAdvice.java:47)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionAdvice$1.execute(RetryingTransactionAdvice.java:64)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionAdvice.invoke(RetryingTransactionAdvice.java:67)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.findSites(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.site.script.ScriptSiteService.findSites(ScriptSiteService.java:280)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_live_search_sites_get_js_2._c_getSiteResults_7(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/live-search-sites.get.js:258)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_live_search_sites_get_js_2.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/live-search-sites.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_live_search_sites_get_js_2._c_liveSearch_5(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/live-search-sites.get.js:161)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_live_search_sites_get_js_2.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/live-search-sites.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_live_search_sites_get_js_2._c_main_10(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/live-search-sites.get.js:299)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_live_search_sites_get_js_2.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/live-search-sites.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:74)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_live_search_sites_get_js_2._c_script_0(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/live-search-sites.get.js:302)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_live_search_sites_get_js_2.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/live-search-sites.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_live_search_sites_get_js_2.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/live-search-sites.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_live_search_sites_get_js_2.exec(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/live-search-sites.get.js)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:502)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:200)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1364)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:482)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:551)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:619)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:399)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:280)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
```

Screenshot:-

[image: image preview]

Also when I go to all documents then also I'm getting some error.

Screenshot:-

[image: doc]
[image: console ss]

**When I search for a document then I'm getting below error.**

```
2017-01-18 16:24:39,049  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-bio-8080-exec-1] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 00180010 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 00180091 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js': 00180090 Failed to execute search: +PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:swsdp/cm:documentLibrary//*" +(TYPE:"cm:content" OR  TYPE:"bcpg:entityV2") -TYPE:"cm:systemfolder" -TYPE:"fm:forums" -TYPE:"fm:forum" -TYPE:"fm:topic" -TYPE:"fm:post" -TYPE:"bcpg:entityListItem" -ASPECT:"bcpg:compositeVersion" -ASPECT:"bcpg:hiddenFolder" -ASPECT:"cm:checkedOut" 
 org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 00180010 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 00180091 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js': 00180090 Failed to execute search: +PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:swsdp/cm:documentLibrary//*" +(TYPE:"cm:content" OR  TYPE:"bcpg:entityV2") -TYPE:"cm:systemfolder" -TYPE:"fm:forums" -TYPE:"fm:forum" -TYPE:"fm:topic" -TYPE:"fm:post" -TYPE:"bcpg:entityListItem" -ASPECT:"bcpg:compositeVersion" -ASPECT:"bcpg:hiddenFolder" -ASPECT:"cm:checkedOut" 
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:482)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:551)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:619)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:399)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:280)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 00180091 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js': 00180090 Failed to execute search: +PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:swsdp/cm:documentLibrary//*" +(TYPE:"cm:content" OR  TYPE:"bcpg:entityV2") -TYPE:"cm:systemfolder" -TYPE:"fm:forums" -TYPE:"fm:forum" -TYPE:"fm:topic" -TYPE:"fm:post" -TYPE:"bcpg:entityListItem" -ASPECT:"bcpg:compositeVersion" -ASPECT:"bcpg:hiddenFolder" -ASPECT:"cm:checkedOut" 
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:204)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1364)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 00180090 Failed to execute search: +PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:swsdp/cm:documentLibrary//*" +(TYPE:"cm:content" OR  TYPE:"bcpg:entityV2") -TYPE:"cm:systemfolder" -TYPE:"fm:forums" -TYPE:"fm:forum" -TYPE:"fm:topic" -TYPE:"fm:post" -TYPE:"bcpg:entityListItem" -ASPECT:"bcpg:compositeVersion" -ASPECT:"bcpg:hiddenFolder" -ASPECT:"cm:checkedOut" 
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.queryResultMeta(Search.java:1007)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.queryResultSet(Search.java:758)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.query(Search.java:551)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_v2_doclist_get_js_8._c_doclist_getAllNodes_15(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js:919)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_v2_doclist_get_js_8.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_v2_doclist_get_js_8._c_doclist_main_16(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js:983)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_v2_doclist_get_js_8.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:74)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_v2_doclist_get_js_8._c_script_0(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js:1208)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_v2_doclist_get_js_8.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_v2_doclist_get_js_8.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_v2_doclist_get_js_8.exec(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.js)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:502)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:200)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 00180089 
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:540)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:51)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:348)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.SearcherComponent.query(SearcherComponent.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1072.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.query(SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1072.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.queryResultMeta(Search.java:916)
    ... 61 more
```

**alfresco-global.properties file at alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes**

```
dir.root=/Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/alf_data

# Alfresco Repo Webapp (alfresco.war) context, ports etc
alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=http

# Alfresco Share Webapp (share.war) context, ports etc
share.context=share
share.host=127.0.0.1
share.port=8080
share.protocol=http

# Use Solr4 as that is used by default with Alfresco 5
index.subsystem.name=solr4
solr.host=127.0.0.1
solr.port=8080
solr.secureComms=none

# Setting Solr backup for the future. Tweak this if needed (ideally in other env properties files)
solr.backup.alfresco.cronExpression=0 30 2 * * ? 2050
solr.backup.archive.cronExpression=0 30 3 * * ? 2050
solr.backup.alfresco.remoteBackupLocation=${dir.root}/solr4Backup/alfresco
solr.backup.archive.remoteBackupLocation=${dir.root}/solr4Backup/archive

# We are in the local DEV properties file, no need for Solr backup
solr.backup.alfresco.numberToKeep=0
solr.backup.archive.numberToKeep=0

# These jobs seem to require Lucene (Unsupported Operation with Solr) so we disable them / set to future date
# See https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=41597
# If you want to enable them (and so full WQS functionality), please also set index.subsystem.name=lucene
wcmqs.dynamicCollectionProcessor.schedule=0 30 2 * * ? 2060
wcmqs.feedbackProcessor.schedule=0 40 2 * * ? 2060
wcmqs.publishQueueProcessor.schedule=0 50 2 * * ? 2060

# Fail or not when there are node integrity checker errors
integrity.failOnError=true

# Database connection properties
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.username=alfresco
db.password=admin
db.name=alfresco
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}
# Note: your database must also be able to accept at least this many connections.  Please see your database documentation for instructions on how to configure this.
db.pool.max=275
db.pool.validate.query=SELECT 1

# File servers related properties
# For local runs we disable CIFS and FTP
cifs.enabled=false
ftp.enabled=false

# added by MA 25th April
googledocs.enabled=true

### Solr indexing ###
index.subsystem.name=solr4
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
solr.port.ssl=8443


I'm not getting what exactly wrong with database or solr4 or what is making this all wrong.
```

Any help is appreciated !!!

Comment: Looks like your Solr server is not happy. Maybe there are exceptions further up in the log that would offer you additional clues. Also, have you tried blowing away your Solr index and re-indexing? You also appear to be running some add-ons. You might check with the add-on author to see if you are experiencing a known issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed below comments and solutions, that fixed my issue.

Post link is provided below for reference.

[Not able to select a tag in Alfresco Community 5.0.d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707985/not-able-to-select-a-tag-in-alfresco-community-5-0-d/41756010#41756010)

Comment: Please explain the solution in your answer, rather than only posting a link. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers